# node request vs python session

Tags: python, node.js, session, node-request

I have a working node.js script which written using the node.js request module.
I'm trying to convert this script to python with the session module.
I'm new to python and I followed the python docs as it mentioned. but I'm struggling to get my code works.
the problem I'm having is sending the cookie values in the subsequent requests with the session module.
as per the docs it is saving cookies and send them automatically in any requests after that. but

here is my working node.js script

```
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');

const getOptions = {
    jar:true,
    followAllRedirects:true,
    method:'GET',
    url:'https://dummyurl.com'
};

request.get(getOptions,(err,response,html)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log('error in request');
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {

        const postOptions = {
            jar:true,
            followAllRedirects: true,
            method:'POST',
            url:'https://dummyurl.com',
            form:{
                'data':{
                    'page':2
                }
            }

        };

        request.post(postOptions,(err,response,html)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log('post err');
                console.log(err);
            }
            else {
                fs.writeFileSync('pyres.html',html,'utf8');
            }
        })
    }
});
```

this is my python conversion of above script

```
s = requests.Session()
url= 'https://dummyurl.com'
response = s.get(url)
print(response.cookies)
data_url = 'https://dummyurl.com/'
postData = {
    "data":{
        "page":2
    }
}

resultResponse = s.post(data_url,data=postData)
print(resultResponse.content)
```

Can anyone points me out any mistake in this code?

Answer (score 0):

actually the problem was in data format.
in nodejs I post it like this

```
{'data':{'page':2} }
```

but in python it should be converted like this

```
{
    'data[page]': '2'
}
```

not sure why it was not worked in normal json format in python